# Don't understand func strings.TrimLeft in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to test code that uses [`func strings.TrimLeft`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimLeft). I needed to see an MVCE of it in action, so I went to [the API specification](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimLeft).

It came with an example, which I exported, with the following code:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print(strings.TrimLeft("¡¡¡Hello, Gophers!!!", "!¡"))
}
```

Upon running it, you get `Hello, Gophers!!!`

I decided to prepend the input string, changing the code to

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print(strings.TrimLeft("irrelevant text¡¡¡Hello, Gophers!!!", "!¡"))
}
```

The result string is the whole input string: `irrelevant text¡¡¡Hello, Gophers!!!`

Aren't at least the cutset characters supposed to be removed?!

Comment: Nope, you got that wrong. TrimLeft would do the trimming from left with the supplied characters. In your second case it is not starting with trim chars so there is nothing to be trimmed from left. (I didn't down vote - someone meant read the docs I guess) - docs from your link clearly says "TrimLeft returns a slice of the string s with all leading Unicode code points contained in cutset removed."

Comment: Let me see if I understand that:

`TrimLeft` trims from the left iff the string to be trimmed starts with characters in the cutset?

Comment: Yes, I just pasted docs saying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an industry standard that `trim` implies a proper suffix or prefix.

`trimLeft` will only remove matching characters from the beginning of the string and stop on the first non-match. In your example, the "i" of "irrelevant" is the first character it checks. It fails the check, so it stops trimming (i.e. it does nothing).

`trimRight`, by comparison, removes matches starting from the end of the string in descending index order.

Answer (score 0):

> Aren't at least the cutset characters supposed to be removed?!

All of the ones at the beginning of the string. There are zero of those, so zero characters are removed.